# Pressure variation created due to just changing the configuration of the system

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure

Let there be a beaker that has a opening in the top and now we just place some kind of a metal plate or something due to which the top gets closed and we can consider the system to be isolated now. What would be the pressure inside? Would it change ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it depends on how good of a heat conductor the material used for the body of the beaker and the top is. As you say, you can't isolate the system by a metal plate or (*something like that*) on the top. The glass used in the beaker may be considered to be a good insulator to some extent but the  material used for the top can't be. The system may not be completely isolated and as a result allow transfer of mass or energy or both.

We can also get it by applying the famous equation of state for ideal gases to our system (the beaker). Air can be approximated to be an ideal gas for a while.
$$P_\text{sys}=\frac{nRT_\text{sys}}V$$

Here we can clearly see that in the system you suggest, either $n$ or $T$ or both may change which will affect the pressure inside. So unless you attain a very good level of isolation like in a thermos flask, $P_\text{sys}$ and $T_\text{sys}$ will very soon change to match $P_\text{surr}$ and $T_\text{surr}$.